# How to scale Druid's batch ingestion job?

Tags: druid

I've setup a Druid cluster on 3 different machines with a master, data and query server. I've scaled the machines to be 48 vCPU and 200GB, but I'm still running into this error when running a batch Druid ingestion job on a large parquet file (1 GB). How do I scale the jvm.config, or the runtime.properties to support my large file ingestion?

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write(FileDispatcherImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:79) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:280) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.druid.java.util.common.io.smoosh.FileSmoosher$Outer.write(FileSmoosher.java:458) ~[druid-core-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
    at org.apache.druid.java.util.common.io.smoosh.FileSmoosher$1.write(FileSmoosher.java:196) ~[druid-core-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:203) ~[guava-16.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.druid.segment.writeout.FileWriteOutBytes.writeTo(FileWriteOutBytes.java:130) ~[druid-processing-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
    at org.apache.druid.segment.data.GenericIndexedWriter.writeToSingleFile(GenericIndexedWriter.java:354) ~[druid-processing-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
    at org.apache.druid.segment.data.GenericIndexedWriter.writeTo(GenericIndexedWriter.java:332) ~[druid-processing-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
    at org.apache.druid.segment.serde.DictionaryEncodedColumnPartSerde$SerializerBuilder$1.writeTo(DictionaryEncodedColumnPartSerde.java:268) ~[druid-processing-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
    at org.apache.druid.segment.column.ColumnDescriptor.writeTo(ColumnDescriptor.java:95) ~[druid-processing-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
    at org.apache.druid.segment.IndexMergerV9.makeColumn(IndexMergerV9.java:633) ~[druid-processing-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
    at org.apache.druid.segment.IndexMergerV9.makeIndexFiles(IndexMergerV9.java:334) ~[druid-processing-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
    at org.apache.druid.segment.IndexMergerV9.merge(IndexMergerV9.java:1303) ~[druid-processing-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
    at org.apache.druid.segment.IndexMergerV9.multiphaseMerge(IndexMergerV9.java:1120) ~[druid-processing-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
    at org.apache.druid.segment.IndexMergerV9.persist(IndexMergerV9.java:1024) ~[druid-processing-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
    at org.apache.druid.segment.IndexMerger.persist(IndexMerger.java:225) ~[druid-processing-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
    at org.apache.druid.segment.realtime.appenderator.AppenderatorImpl.persistHydrant(AppenderatorImpl.java:1525) ~[druid-server-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
    at org.apache.druid.segment.realtime.appenderator.AppenderatorImpl.access$100(AppenderatorImpl.java:114) ~[druid-server-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
    at org.apache.druid.segment.realtime.appenderator.AppenderatorImpl$2.call(AppenderatorImpl.java:653) ~[druid-server-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
    ... 4 more
    Suppressed: org.apache.druid.java.util.common.IOE: Expected [373,361,476] bytes, only saw [204,798,487], potential corruption?
        at org.apache.druid.java.util.common.io.smoosh.FileSmoosher$1.close(FileSmoosher.java:243) ~[druid-core-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
        at org.apache.druid.segment.IndexMergerV9.makeColumn(IndexMergerV9.java:634) ~[druid-processing-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
        at org.apache.druid.segment.IndexMergerV9.makeIndexFiles(IndexMergerV9.java:334) ~[druid-processing-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
        at org.apache.druid.segment.IndexMergerV9.merge(IndexMergerV9.java:1303) ~[druid-processing-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
        at org.apache.druid.segment.IndexMergerV9.multiphaseMerge(IndexMergerV9.java:1120) ~[druid-processing-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
        at org.apache.druid.segment.IndexMergerV9.persist(IndexMergerV9.java:1024) ~[druid-processing-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
        at org.apache.druid.segment.IndexMerger.persist(IndexMerger.java:225) ~[druid-processing-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
        at org.apache.druid.segment.realtime.appenderator.AppenderatorImpl.persistHydrant(AppenderatorImpl.java:1525) ~[druid-server-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
        at org.apache.druid.segment.realtime.appenderator.AppenderatorImpl.access$100(AppenderatorImpl.java:114) ~[druid-server-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
        at org.apache.druid.segment.realtime.appenderator.AppenderatorImpl$2.call(AppenderatorImpl.java:653) ~[druid-server-25.0.0.jar:25.0.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [SQL Based Ingestion](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/multi-stage-query/index.html), if not, it likely makes sense to do so, since it is more efficient than native ingestion.

Take a look at [how it uses resources](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/multi-stage-query/concepts.html#multi-stage-query-tasks). Notice that each task will need local storage for the input file(s) (one input file processed at a time in each task), aprox. 2GB per task for temporary storage for segment building and enough space to store the complete ingestion dataset (compressed) during the shuffle phase.

Also make sure that you configure the Peons with enough resources to execute the task ([see druid.indexer.runner.javaOptsArray](https://druid.apache.org/docs/24.0.0/configuration/index.html#middlemanager-and-peons) ).